# Probability of two lotteries

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I recently came across the following question that is a pretty interesting real-word application of probability.

> Suppose there are two lotteries, each with $n$ tickets and a payoff of $100. Is it it better (in terms of expected gain) to buy two tickets from the first lottery, or one from each?

Here is my thinking for the first scenario:
Define $A_1$ to be the event that the first ticket is a winner, and $A_2$ the event that the second ticket is a winner. A couple observations:
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2) = 0$$
$$P(Winning) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) = \frac{2}{n}$$
For the second scenario:
$$P(A_1 \cap A_2) =P(A_1)P(A_2) =\frac{1}{n^2}\neq 0$$
$$P(Winning) = P(A_1)+P(A_2) - P(A_1 \cap A_2)$$
by the Inclusion-Exclusion principle.
Therefore, it is better to buy $2$ tickets from the same lottery:
$$P(Winning\ In\ Scenario\ 1)=\frac{2}{n} >\frac{2}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2} =P(Winning\ In\ Scenario\ 2) $$Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I would probably use expected outcome to calculate this. With the first strategy, your expected gain is $\$\frac{200}{n}$ because the expected gain from each lottery is $\$\frac{100}{n}$ and you are playing 2 identical lotteries. With the second strategy, your expected value is also $\$\frac{200}{n}$ because you have a $\frac{2}{n}$ chance of winning $\$100$. It seems that the two payoffs are identical (except for in trivial cases like $n=2$, when you should certainly by two tickets from one lottery).

Comment: You are more likely to win something by buying two tickets in a single lottery.  You are more likely to win a double prize if you buy one ticket in each of two lotteries